# Checking out multiple files of the same name in Git

Tags: eclipse, git

I merged from several other branches on a big project with multiple eclipse projects, and ended up with a bunch of org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs settings being changed, that I'd like to revert on my branch. Is there magic command I can use to 'reset' only these files, over all the eclipse projects in my git repo?

I tried something along the lines of

```
git checkout origin/BRANCH_WITH_CORRECT_FILES -- *org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

This returns

```
error: pathspec '*org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Is this because of the *? How can I get around it?

Comment: Have you tried using two asterisk? Like this: `git checkout origin/BRANCH_WITH_CORRECT_FILES -- *org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs*`?

Comment: I get the same issue if I try two asterisks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that `git checkout` doesn't search in subdirectories. To checkout files using asterisks you have to specify the folder where git can find them.

Nethertheless it's possible to checkout all files with a specific string in their name, regardless of their location in the repository. To achieve this we have to combine a number of commands.

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only <branch> | grep <pattern>
```

This will return a list of all files with the given pattern in their name; we pass the output of this command to `git checkout` which will update the working tree accordingly.

```
git checkout <branch> -- $(git ls-tree -r --name-only <branch> | grep <pattern>)
```

And the magic is done.

---

For easier usage I would suggest creating an alias in your global *gitconfig*.

```
git config --global alias.super-checkout '!f() { git checkout $1 -- $(git ls-tree -r --name-only $1 | grep "$2"); }; f'
```

After this you can take use of the command with `git super-checkout <branch> <pattern>`, or in your case:

```
git super-checkout origin/BRANCH_WITH_CORRECT_FILES org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

***Note**: You can obviously use a different alias than `super-checkout`.*

---

Take a look at the [`git ls-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html) for better understanding.