# git checkout modified file without copy-pasting full file path

Tags: git, git-checkout

`git status` shows something like

```
git status
# On branch icc-server-send-metric-values
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   java/com/me/cards/preview/preview-card.js
```

I want to checkout the file, but without retyping it or copy pasting it. The closest command is `add -i` but this only really cares about the index, not checking out. What's a good workflow here?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27443790/2274224). It's not exactly what you asked for but can be applied to this situation.

Comment: `git diff-files --name-only` lists all the changed files if you ever want to have the names for a script or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tab-completion, which virtually every shell provides. There are lots of articles which will help you set this up, including [this one](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion) for Bash.

As for pure Git solutions:

If that is the only modification, use `git checkout .` to discard all changes.

If you want to keep some changes and discard others, use `git checkout -p` to interactively discard changes in the working directory.

When Git prompts you with changes from each file you want to discard, use `a`:

> a - discard this hunk and all later hunks in the file

When Git prompts you with the changes from each file you want to keep, use `d`:

> d - do not discard this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file

Comment: tab completion doesn't work because my path is horrendously larger than in my toy example, but I didn't know about checkout -p, that's what I needed and thanks.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had put the meaning of other options too. `Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]?`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal That's out of scope for this answer, and help is already available inline. Just press `?`

Comment: @meagar: thanks for mentioning `?` since at the first look of options, it is not very clear which one should I use before doing anything wrong.

Comment: @meagar I also felt that the answer was incomplete without mentioning how to **not** discard changes in the other files, so I added that bit to the end of your answer. How does it look?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "plugin" for Git, which is perfectly suited for this use case.

It's called [`git number`](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number) and enables you to reference changed files via numbers.

---

The "plugin" adds a `git number` command, which - without any further parameters - is equivalent to a `git status` but with leading numbers.

```
$ git number
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

1       a/b/c/d/e/f/g/test2

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If you prefer `git status -s` (as I do) `git number` has you covered.

```
$ git number -s
1 ?? a/b/c/d/e/f/g/test2
```

After that you can reference the files via their number by prepending each command with `number`. A `git add` could look like this:

```
$ git number add 1
git add a/b/c/d/e/f/g/test2
```

`git number` echos the executed command so you can ensure you used the correct number. `git add` was just an example, you can use any command and prepend it with `number`.

Furthermore it supports ranges; if you want to add the files 5-10 you can just use `git number add 5-10` and `git number` will understand you.

---

For any further questions I would suggest to simply take a look at the [github repository](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number).